# python bubble sort, what am I missing? ((

Tags: python, bubble-sort

```py
def countSwaps(a):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        for j in range(len(a)-1-i):
            count += 1
            if a[j] > a[j+1]:
                a[j],a[j+1] = a[j+1],a[j]
    return count
countSwaps()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    countSwaps(a)
```

Throws a runtime error

anyone can help me? what am I missing here?

thanks a lot!

Comment: You're missing your code. Screenshots don't count. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: line 18 + next time post that code here instead of screenshooting it

Comment: P.S next time please read "how to ask a question"

Comment: line 18, you're missing your argument `a`

Comment: Please note that [an image of your code is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

```
def countSwaps(a):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        for j in range(len(a)-1-i):
            count += 1
            if a[j] > a[j+1]:
                a[j],a[j+1] = a[j+1],a[j]
    return count
countSwaps()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    countSwaps(a)
```

Returns the error

```
TypeError: countSwaps() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

So I removed the `countSwaps()` After which I input:

```
1
2 3 4 5
```

I first input a number in order to not fail the creation of `n`. Then a list of numbers divided by spaces. This works without throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you called the function outside the main block and way before the initialization of the list in the line 10 i.e. `countSwaps()` In case you want it to work both ways you must give it a keyword argument in definition i.e. `def countSwaps(a=[1, 3, 4, 2]):`. In this code even the `n` isn't used which drops the quality of code.

In Short: Either remove line 10 `countSwaps()` or add keyword argument in definition.